# using TRIE for strings?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, trees, strings, information-retrieval

I saw the following question online:

`Init` - Initlize data structure in O(1).

`Insert(s)` - Add string s to your Data Structure in O(|s|).

`Remove(s)` - Remove string s from your Data Structure in O(|s|).

`PrefixExists(s)` - return True if there exists 2 different strings s1,s2 (different from each other) such that s is a prefix of s1 and s1 is a prefix of s2 in O(|s|).

---

It's clear that I have to use TRIE but I'm not sure which data to save in each node and how to update it.

I though about saving a data which is equal to the sum of the data of children + how many `$` signs children have ($ is the end of each string) while this worked for few strings I strongly believe it's wrong.

Comment: Storing an alphabetical letter in each "cell" should suffice.

Comment: @nirshahar can you elaborate?

Comment: Where online did you see this?  Please credit the original source of all problems that you post here, and make sure to credit all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing